# iTunes 11 - List Format

Tags: macos, itunes

I upgraded to iTunes 11 and am really upset that they took away the standard list format. Does anyone know how to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is not you can't get it all back.

However you get some of it back by choosing songs under the insert showing the current song and progress. You also need to choose View->Column Browser->Show Column Browser